# Gulp tasks from within other Gulp tasks?

Tags: javascript, build-process, gulp

I have a Gulp build task that is made up of other build tasks similar to this:

```
gulp.task('build', ['build-html', 'build-css', 'build-js', 'build-images']);
```

The thing I hate about this is that the `build` task doesn't run until after the dependencies are finished:

```
Starting 'build-html'...
Finished 'build-html' after 1 s
Starting 'build-css'...
Finished 'build-css' after 1 s
Starting 'build-js'...
Finished 'build-js' after 1 s
Starting 'build-images'...
Finished 'build-images' after 1 s
Starting 'build'...
Finished 'build' after 1 ms
```

Now obviously, `build` is not supposed to run at all until it's dependencies are finished, so it's working as expected. But this results in the console saying `build` took only 1 ms when in reality it should say it took 4 seconds, since all it's dependencies took that long. It would be nice if it looked something like this:

```
Starting 'build'...
Starting 'build-html'...
Finished 'build-html' after 1 s
Starting 'build-css'...
Finished 'build-css' after 1 s
Starting 'build-js'...
Finished 'build-js' after 1 s
Starting 'build-images'...
Finished 'build-images' after 1 s
Finished 'build' after 4 s
```

Notice how `build` is the first thing that "starts", then all the dependencies run, then `build` finishes.

So what I'm wondering, instead of using task dependencies, can I just call each task one at a time from within the `build` task? If so, what command do I use to do this?

Is this a bad idea? Is there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to be able to print the total time for all the build tasks in this way?

Comment: I'm just curious how long the total build time is. The above example is greatly simplified. In reality some build tasks take MUCH longer when they involve uploading files to remote servers, source control interactions, optimization of hundreds of images, etc...

Comment: Actually you're not running `build` first, you're running it after the all the tasks depencies. Do you just want to know how much all tasks took to perform dist, or do you need perform the tasks in sequence? Edit: ( I read your comment before )

Comment: Is it also important to be able to see how long each individual task took?

Comment: I know build isn't running first. That's why I'm wondering if its possible to simply call other tasks from within a task. In some cases the tasks run async. In some cases they are synchronous. It just depends on the task and if any of them depend on each other. I guess I'm just looking for the total time.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use the [runSequence](https://github.com/OverZealous/run-sequence) plugin to do what you want.

Since the only purpose of your `build` task is to launch all the `build-*` tasks with no specific order, this can look like:

```
var rs = require('run-sequence');

gulp.task('build', function (cb) {
  rs(['build-css', 'build-html', 'build-js', 'build-images'], cb);
});
```