# Gulp reports tasks in incorrect order

Tags: gulp

Been using Gulp (3.9.0) for a while now and am loving it, but there's one aspect of that bugs me. Wondering if I'm doing something wrong, or thinking about the functionality the wrong way.

Lets say I have a task like this:

```
gulp.task("build", ["build-js", "build-css"]);
```

I get an output like this:

```
Starting 'build-js'...
Finished 'build-js' after 22 μs
Starting 'build-css'...
Finished 'build-css' after 2.48 μs
Starting 'build'...
Finished 'build' after 2.09 μs
```

...because 'build-js' and 'build-css' are dependencies, not sub-tasks.

But, I would want an output like this:

```
Starting 'build'...
Starting 'build-js'...
Finished 'build-js' after 22 μs
Starting 'build-css'...
Finished 'build-css' after 2.48 μs
Finished 'build' after 26.57 μs
```

...because from my perspective, build-js and build-css should be sub-tasks.

I can get this functionality by doing:

```
gulp.task("build", () => {
    gulp.start("build-js", "build-css");
});
```

...but the folks behind gulp don't want us using the start method.

There's a similar question from 2014 here: [Gulp tasks from within other Gulp tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27710574/gulp-tasks-from-within-other-gulp-tasks) but it hasn't gotten much love.  Mostly I'm interested in doing this because I have about 20 different 'subtasks' that run in the build task, all linked through dependencies, and the output order gets confusing.

So to summarize... 
Is there a better way to get my desired functionality that is more of the gulp way?
...or am I thinking about this in a totally wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the order the tasks are executing, it's just the way Gulp does things. If there's no dependency between two tasks they will each start as soon as they can. The only way, as far as I know, to change the print order is to actually change the order of the tasks. You could do this with [run-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence). This task:

```
gulp.task('build', function (callback) {
    return runSequence('build-js', 'build-css', callback);
});
```

... would result in this output:

```
Starting 'build'...
Starting 'build-js'...
Finished 'build-js' after 25 ms
Starting 'build-css'...
Finished 'build-css' after 2.02 ms
Finished 'build' after 30 ms
```

But I wouldn't particular recommend it. It's kind of going against the way Gulp is designed and could affect performance on a large project.

Comment: Thanks.  Good answer, just not what I was hoping for :-p.  I know gulp runs things in parallel, and using run-sequence would run them in serial instead, which would affect performance.  IMO, doing it the 'gulp way' makes the output more-or-less useless, because it appears like the tasks aren't running in the order specified.  This is especially confusing when running lots of tasks that may have their own output (like running tests, or installing packages).